# How can I reorder elements in Realm LinkingObjects?

Tags: swift, realm

I have an Item data class, and each Item has one parent and many children Items, which are LinkingObjects from the parent property.
A simplified version:

```
@objcMembers class Item: Object {
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var parent: Item?
    let children = LinkingObjects(fromType: Item.self, property: "parent")
}
```

I need to be able to reorder the children, and persist that change. It seems that because LinkingObjects is a container type this wouldn't be possible? In this case, how would you recommend I approach this--should I change `children` to a normal `List<Item>` and just manually update the realm two ways every time? Is there a better solution?

Comment: To help me answer, can you (a) provide the definitions of your Realm types (for completeness and better understanding), and (b) explain how you want the children to be ordered and why it matters?

Comment: You need to set a property based on which you can create a sort. LinkingObjects can be converted into RealmResults (in Android anyway, so hopefully in iOS too), and RealmResults can be sorted.

Comment: When you say 'reorder the children and persist that change' what does that mean exactly? in what way do you want it 'persisted'? As mentioned above - we need to see your Realm objects and understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: There's only one object, ```Item```, and it's an infinite tree--like a file system. Each Item object has pointers to its parent item and a LinkingObjects object representing its children, as well as other attributes like name, date, etc. I've updated the question with a simplified version of the data model. 
The order in which the children appear matters, because users will want to choose their own ordering based on which items they want to see first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The order in which the children appear matters, because users will want to choose their own ordering based on which items they want to see first.

The important part here is that you want to control the 'order in which the children appear'. If you can recognise the difference between the 'model' of the data and the 'view' of the data then you can work out the answer. Remember that the Realm model representation is not under your control, and you don't need it to be. How it's stored in the Realm database is not your problem.

In reality, the results of the `LinkingObjects` field when you request it will probably be the result of a database query, and not a straight pull from a table. So the order of objects in the field may be inconsistent, or adding further linked objects may cause the extra item to appear anywhere in the results.

As you say, the important thing is the order in which the children **appear**. And this can be controlled through a query. The `LinkingObjects` type allows you to query directly, i.e. you can call:

```
item.children.sorted(byKeyPath: "title")
```

One suggestion would be to add an extension to your model type to handle the sorting for you, providing an accessor for each sort type you require, e.g.:

```
extension Item
{
  var childrenSortedByTitle: Results<Item>
  {
    return children.sorted(byKeyPath: "title")
  }
}
```

Or you could make that a function with an `ascending` boolean parameter to use in the query. Or you could add a second query for ascending/descending. And you can add extra queries for each other parameter you would like to sort by. Or you could define an enum of sort fields and pass that it as an argument. Whichever of these methods works best for you. But it is definitely worth hiding the query details in the class extension itself (IMHO).